# Importing GeoJSON file to feature collection into Google Earth Engine using Google Colab

Tags: geojson, geocoding, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am new to code and using Earth Engine Python API. I converted a shapefile to a GeoJSON. I need to convert my geojson file to a feature collection and upload it into my Google Earth Engine repository. I am using this code (check picture), however I get an error that says

> EEException: Invalid GeoJSON geometry.

I then use a GeoJSON online validator tool, and it seems like my file is valid and the geometry type is a point. My GeoJSON is a feature collection with more than 3000 points. How can I overcome this? I added a block with my code, and screenshots of the GeoJSON file.

Code

```
# Specify the Google Drive file ID of the shapefile
file_id = '1iA9L6tn0dwVlABPngFAgjRxd8xXET1c4'
file_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Data/TrainingSet_SabieCroc/Training_setSc.shp'
url = f'https://drive.google.com/uc?id={file_id}'

# Read the shapefile into a GeoDataFrame
training_data = gpd.read_file(file_path)

#print (training_data)

# Convert the GeoDataFrame to GeoJSON and save it
geojson_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Data/TrainingSet_SabieCroc/Training_setSc.geojson'
training_data.to_file(geojson_path, driver='GeoJSON')

# Read the GeoJSON file as a dictionary
with open(geojson_path, 'r') as f:
    geojson_data = json.load(f)

# Convert the GeoJSON file to a feature collection
training_set= ee.FeatureCollection(geojson_data)

#Specify the asset ID where you want to upload the feature collection
#asset_id = 'projects/thandeka-skosana/assets/training_set'

# Export the feature collection to an Earth Engine asset
#export_task = ee.batch.Export.table.toAsset(
    #collection=training_set,
    #description='Export Training Set',
    #assetId=asset_id
#)

# Start the export task
#export_task.start()
```

[image: snapshot of geojson]

[image: geojson geometry]

Comment: Please put code and data in your Question as text, not screenshots. You don't want to require those who want to help you to retype all your code and data.

Comment: It looks like your points have Z coordinates, but [`ee.Geometry.Point`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-geometry-point) only supports X and Y. You'll need to remove the Z coordinates from the `GeoDataFrame` before turning it into a `FeatureCollection`.

Comment: @AaronZuspan I did remove the Z coordinates but it still didn't work. Thanks for trying to help.